# Having nginx return a 503 if a file exists

Tags: nginx

I'm looking for my nginx server to return a 503, if the maintenance page exists.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;

    server_name  _;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # Return a 503 error if the maintenance page exists. 
        if (-f /var/www/xxx/shared/public/system/maintenance.html) {
            return 503;
        }
    }

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   location = /404.html {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html 
    error_page 500 502 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    # Return a 503 error if the maintenance page exists.
    error_page 503 @503;

    location @503 {
    # Serve static assets if found.
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    # Set root to the shared directory.
    root /var/www/xxx/shared/public;
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
}
```

this seems correct, but it's not working. I have verified that the file is in the correct place but this is not working as expected. I'm still getting the same old nginx error page.

I have reloaded it, but still same response.

edit : Placed whole conf file.

Comment: You probably need an `error_page` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

Comment: Yea. I thought that too. I updated the question with the whole conf file.

Comment: I haven't tested this - but maybe your `if` statement, needs to be inside the `location / { ... }` block, as that is where the URI is initially processed.

Comment: Yea. I just tried that as well. still redirects to the 50x.html file.

Comment: I have tested your method (even with the `if` statement in the original location) and it works for me. If 50x is triggering, it's probably a 500 error - you should check the error log.

Comment: Oh ok. Here is something. 
2016/11/17 16:56:51 [crit] 18154#0: *8 stat() "/var/www/xxx/shared/public/system/maintenance.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 96.119.91.55, server: xxx.xcal.tv, 

maybe this is a permissions error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128377/discussion-between-r-j-robinson-and-richard-smith).

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet on my setup

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;
    server_name my-awesome-website.com;

    location / {

        if (-f $document_root/underconstruction.html) {
            return 503;
        }

    }

    error_page 503 @maintenance;

    location @maintenance {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /underconstruction.html break;
    }

    location @maintenance ~ \.(jpg|png) {
        root /www/media;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nifty snippet, you can also add `return 200` for the images location too.